# Android, ImageView in message Balloon

Tags: android, xml, layout, imageview, messenger

It is interesting to find out how to add an image to the container(balloon) line in the list? **full coverage of the region(balloon)** (Android)

```
    __________
   |imageVeiw |
  /imageView  |
  \imageView  |
   |__________|
```

UPDATE:

I find solved.
Result pic:
http://i57.tinypic.com/dndok0.jpg

```
public void makeMaskImage(ImageView mImageView, int mContent)
    {
        Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), mContent);
        Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.mask);
        int h = original.getHeight()/(original.getWidth()/mask.getWidth());
        original = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original, mask.getWidth(), h, false);
```

`Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(result);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(null);
    mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
    //mImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.frame);
}`

Comment: Hi could you put some code so we can understand clearly what you are trying to do ? Thanks

Comment: I speaking about 2 row on the picture https://lh4.ggpht.com/jxl585Pkj-bb4uuKxpoXCW2A3r8Ll6PmzTnoyVHd2shi10PSLVrThuA-EGePLBaaUA=h900

Answer (score 0):

Convert your balloon image into ninepatch image using this(http://draw9patch.com/).while converting into 9patch set equal space in four side of image area. And also download and refer this tutorial(http://javapapers.com/android/android-chat-bubble/) for clear idea.

Comment: No, i speaking about 2 row on the picture https://lh4.ggpht.com/jxl585Pkj-bb4uuKxpoXCW2A3r8Ll6PmzTnoyVHd2shi10PSLVrThuA-EGePLBaaUA=h900

Comment: This not possible i think. Better u set individual balloon for each image. It looks good and it wont affect your design part. Even whatsapp and many chat apps is following same.